# What's the difference between augmented matrix with dotted line and solid line?

Tags: matrices, notation

The augmented matrix below has a solid line between the final column.
$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\
    16 & 32 & 64 & 128 \\
    256 & 512 & 1024 & 2048
  \end{array}\right]
$$
But I've also seen a dotted line used like this. Does a dotted line have a different meaning?
$$
 \left[
\begin{array}{ccc:c}
1 & 2 & 4 & 8 \\ 
16 & 32 & 64 & 128 \\
256 & 512 & 1024 & 2048 \\ 
\end{array} \right] 
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; it's just a matter of style.